Finding all types of end-of-line delimiters in a file
I have the following function to get all of the different types of end-of-line delimiters in a file. There may be one or more, so I want to return an array of all types.
function ddtt_get_file_eol( $file_contents, $incl_code = true ) {
    $types = [
        '\r\n',
        '\n',
        '\r'
    ];
    $found = [];
    foreach ( $types as $type ) {
        if ( $type == '\r\n' ) {
            $regex = "/\r\n/";
        } elseif ( $type == '\n' ) {
            $regex = "/(?<!\r)\n/";
        } else {
            $regex = "/\r(?!\n)/";
        }
        if ( preg_match( $regex, $file_contents ) ) {
            $found[] = ( $incl_code ) ? '<code class="hl">'.$type.'</code>' : $type;
        }
    }
    return $found;
} // End ddtt_get_php_eol()

The problem I am having is that it is recognizing \r\n as two separate types and outputting [ '\n', '\r' ]. I want to output [ '\r\n' ] if it is just using that type, or [ '\r\n', '\n' ] if using both types, etc. How do I modify my code to correctly fetch all types used?

Just a remark to your code: Your array of types could be written as a keyed array instead of a simple array. This would avoid this if, elseif, else. The key could be the type and the value the regular expression.

The result you have can happen, if the file is a mixture of both types of line endings. I unfortunately had the case a few times, working on some big projects on Git, with users working on Windows, others on Linux, and the Git repository not set up properly to auto-convert line endings on commits. Does this result arrive if you edit yourself some test files where you use only one type of line endings?

I can't reproduce the problem. When I call ddtt_get_file_eol("foo\r\nbar\r\n", false) I only get ["\r\n"]. Please provide sample input that has the wrong result.

@PatrickJanser They want that kind of result if the file has a mix of different line breaks. That's why it returns an array.

@Barmar: Yes, I understood that it's what Aristocles wants. But my question is to validate that he actually is testing a file having both line endings and that it may not be a bug in his function.

Exactly. That's why I asked for sample input.

Okay, I've been at this way too long, and didn't think to go back to basics. I tested the code with what @Barmar used and it works fine for all instances. Something else must be wrong with my code, then. I am trying to update a file that splits the lines into an array, updates the specific lines, and then implodes them back into a string. In doing so I am using this to detect what eol delimiter is being used so I can maintain the same delimiters, but give a warning if mixed eols are used. If that makes sense.

Thank you @PatrickJanser for the suggestion on keying the array, too. I had originally done so and through all of my testing I just made the if-statement and didn't revert back.

Wikipedia has a page about different newline styles, it includes LF-CR that is not in your list. Several years ago I used a system that used CR-CR-LF, it is also not in your list. To partially answer your question, I would search for occurrences of [\r\n]+ and add them to a $types list.

Honestly, if your input mixes different types of line ending that's a problem that needs to be solved, ideally at the source, not danced around in the code.

@Sammitch: it unfortunately happens more often that what one would think. His tool could effectively directly return on the first match instead of testing all cases, to be more efficient. But it would be wrong. Testing all types of line endings seems to be the good way of doing it. Even Linux tools like file will return the information of several line ending types if there’s a mixture.

@Sammitch, right, which is why I'm detecting it and giving a warning. What I didn't mention was that when I put it back together it will be using only one type, specified by the user, but recommending the current PHP_EOL value if the user doesn't know which one to choose.

@Aris I don't understand why my answer is marked as unhelpful, but if you are going to sanitize and enforce consistent newline sequences, \R is precisely the solution.  Match all \Rs, then replace with the preferred newline sequence -- done and with no fluffing about.

Let me guess, you are a developer who wants perfect identification of newline sequences regardless of the environment AND you want to keep all of your hair?
PHP has had a solution for this for a long time and it doesn't involve Minoxidil; just use \R.  I'll replace each newline sequence with an asterisk to show how it reliably respects all possible newline sequences across all environments and treats them as whole newline sequences whenever appropriate.
Code: (Demo)
$inputs = [
    'Windows' => "Dog\r\nCat\r\nMouse",
    'Linux' => "Bicycle\nCar\nTrain\nAirplane",
    'Mac' => "iPhone\riPod\rMacBook",
    'Win + Linux' => "int main() {\n   return 0;\r\n}\n",
    'All mixed up' => "This is a Windows new line\r\n, followed by a Linux new line\n and finally an old Mac with a single carriage return\rat the end",
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/\R/', '*', $inputs)
);

Output:
array (
  'Windows' => 'Dog*Cat*Mouse',
  'Linux' => 'Bicycle*Car*Train*Airplane',
  'Mac' => 'iPhone*iPod*MacBook',
  'Win + Linux' => 'int main() {*   return 0;*}*',
  'All mixed up' => 'This is a Windows new line*, followed by a Linux new line* and finally an old Mac with a single carriage return*at the end',
)

If you need an array of newline sequences, just use preg_match_all() with the same, lone pattern. Demo
foreach ($inputs as $env => $input) {
    preg_match_all('/\R/', $input, $matches);
    var_dump(
        $env,
        json_encode($matches[0])
    );
}

Relevant reading on implementations of \R:

Replace multiple new lines with a single newline
Explode PHP string by new line
Reliably split user-submitted textarea value on newlines
Validate predictable phrases in multiline text separated by commas
Split string by new line characters
Remove new line and carriage return characters in a string
How to insert string before last line?
PHP - Export name and email address from file


I didn't DV, but how does this answer the question? They want to detect when multiple newline styles are found in a document. They don't want to replace the newlines with anything.

I also show how to match the newline sequences.  I don't understand how it doesn't solve this (xy) problem.  The asker says: "The problem I am having is that it is recognizing \r\n as two separate types"  -- \R is the most direct, elegant way to solve this problem.

@mickmackusa, I am just now seeing that you replied. I didn't downvote your answer either. Somebody downvoted my question, too.

@Aristocles well, I believe my solution is the absolute best solution for your task.  You are hoping to standardize your text, right?  You don't need to scan the whole document for variations of newlines, just replace newline sequences with preg_replace() and \R.  This answer is much more direct than your accepted answer unless I am misunderstanding something.

@mickmackusa You are correct. I had already accepted the best answer before you added yours, and just saw yours near midnight last night my time, so I wasn't about to get into work mode. This morning after looking into your answer, it does seem like the best solution and I have accepted it as so. I wasn't aware of \R until now. This whole EOL crap is all new to me. XD

In my opinion, your code is fine. It's just your input which is a mixture.
<?php

$LINE_TYPES = [
    '\\r\\n' => '/\\r\\n/',
    '\\n' => '/(?<!\\r)\\n/',
    '\\r' => '/\\r(?!\\n)/',
];

$inputs = [
    'Windows' => "Dog\r\nCat\r\nMouse",
    'Linux' => "Bicycle\nCar\nTrain\nAirplane",
    'Mac' => "iPhone\riPod\rMacBook",
    'Win + Linux' => "int main() {\n   return 0;\r\n}\n",
    'All mixed up' => "This is a Windows new line\r\n, followed by a Linux new line\n and finally an old Mac with a single carriage return\rat the end",
];

foreach ($inputs as $label => $input) {
    $found_types = [];
    foreach ($LINE_TYPES as $type => $regex) {
        if (preg_match($regex, $input)) {
            $found_types[] = $type;
        }
    }
    print "Found types for $label is " . implode(', ', $found_types) . PHP_EOL;
}


Outputs the following:
Found types for Windows is \r\n
Found types for Linux is \n
Found types for Mac is \r
Found types for Win + Linux is \r\n, \n
Found types for All mixed up is \r\n, \n, \r

which seems completely normal.
You can test/play with it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/4ce47
